# Cannot find module 'express' cloudfoundry node08 during deployment

Tags: node.js, deployment, express, cloud-foundry

While deploying the nodejs application in cloudfoundry.. it s giving error "Cannot find module 'express'".. Appreciate any help in this regard.. It is very simple hello world program.. Even the package.json is pretry simple.. Is there any cloudfoundry specific changes that needs to be done..
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to have modules already installed using "npm install". Or, do "npm shrinkwrap", Create package.json file w/ {"ignoreNodeModules": true} to ask CF to install modules in the cloud. See: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCrXhNGDhhY&list=UU0ZYS0Y7b5oiVLvxGf4magw&index=4&feature=plcp